# Firebase database ou API rest PHP MySQL. Qual a melhor escolha e qual a Google recomenda

Tags: android, rest, firebase

Acabei a faculdade no final do ano que se passou. Fiz Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas, e lá tive aula de programação para dispositivos móveis, mais especificamente para Android. Na aula o professor ensinou a desenvolver a persistência de dados sobre uma API em PHP com banco de dados MySQL, basicamente a API recebia requisições via POST e retornava um JSON. Meu TCC foi todo feito nesse esquema.

Agora comecei a desenvolver um aplicativo profissional. Estou usando a mesma estratégia de persistência de dados. Mas como vou trabalhar com sistema de assinatura, comecei a perceber que não seria tão seguro assim esse método, mesmo usando as recomendações (https, MySQL prepare statmant e regras de validação de variáveis no PHP) e também é um tanto um pouco complicado e trabalhoso.

Comecei então uma pesquisa para encontrar outros métodos. Encontrei o firebase realtime database. Me apaixonei! Simples e robusto, sem contar que é integrado ao ecossistema dá Google. Estou me acostumando e aprendendo um pouco mais sobre o conceito do NoSQL.

Então, é uma boa escolha trocar o sistema de API para o firebase? Ou melhor refinar a API e continuar o projeto com a mesma? Só pra complementar, gosto de seguir os padrões da Google.

Queria a opinião de alguém experiente no assunto.